# Find the maximum number of points of intersection of 6 circles.

Tags: logic, permutations, combinations

I know that the answer is 30, but how we are getting to it, that I do not know.
One more thing that I know that the maximum number of intersection of 2 circles is 2.

Comment: The intersection of 2 circles yields 2 intersection points. With 6 circles, one circle touches the other 5 --> 10. The second circle touches the other 4 --> 8. The third circle touches the other 3 --> 6, the fourth circle touches 5th and 6th --> 4, the fifth touches the sixth, twice. We can't say the second touches the other five, b/c we've already counted the touches between 1st and 2nd. It's a combinations problem. So for 6: 10+8+6+4+2 = 30 = 2(1+2+3+4+5)

Answer (score 3):

If every pair of circles can intersect in at most $2$ points, then the max number of intersections among the $6$ circles is twice the number of pairs of circles we can form:
$$2\binom{6}{2}=30$$
**Edit:** following the comment of @David K I will show that we can actually obtain this number. Consider the $6$ circles of radius $10$ centered at $(a,0$) for $a=0,1,2,3,4,5$. Then one can easily check that for all $a,b\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$, the two points
$$\left(\frac{a+b}{2},\pm\sqrt{100-\frac{(a-b)^{2}}{4}}\right)$$
lie on both circles $(x-a)^{2}+y^{2}=100$ and $(x-b)^{2}+y^{2}=100$. I'll mention that to find these points, I subtracted the equations of both circles to obtain 
$$-2bx+b^{2}-(-2ax+a^{2})=0$$
which reduces to $(b-a)(b+a-2x)=0$ and since $a\neq b$ for distinct circles, we must have $x=(a+b)/2$. It is also clear by looking at the $x$-coordinates of these intersection points that they are all distinct, so that the max of $30$ is indeed obtained.

Comment: But one also should show that $30$ intersections are possible.

Comment: The proof that $30$ is possible can be done directly (for example, draw six circles of radius $10$ with their centers evenly spaced $1$ unit apart along a line, and count the intersections). But it does need to be done somehow in order to complete the answer.

Comment: And not just that they're possible, but that it's possible for none of the intersections to coincide.

Comment: yes, this should be part of the answer. I've updated my answer based off @David K's example

Answer (score 0):

Let’s place the first circle.
Now the second circle, which makes 2 intersections.
The third circle gives 4 more intersections.(2 intersections to each circle.)
That will give us 2+4+6+8+10=30 at the end.
I drew a picture with 30 intersections for you.
[image]

Comment: Please don’t say that these are not perfect circles, they still work when they are.